# If I use SqlCommand in a method as a parameter, does it block a SqlConnection dispose?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlconnection, sqlcommand

I'm having connection pool issues on my service (max reached), everywhere that I try to open a connection I wrap it on a `using`  statement to dispose it correctly, but I think something is not allowing it to work. I think it is because I'm using a method that expects a `SqlCommand` as a parameter, this is an example:

```
private void QueryDB(string sConnString, SqlCommand oComm)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(sConnString))
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            oComm.Connection = connection;
            oComm.CommandTimeout = 2;
            oComm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (SqlException e)
        {
            //log exception
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //log exception
        }
    }
}
```

The reason why I do this is because I need to assemble the parameters outside that method, like this:

```
public void Example1()
{
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
    {
        command.CommandText = "SELECT TOP 1 FROM Table ORDER BY column1 DESC";
        QueryDB(_connString, command));
    }
}

public void Example2()
{
    SqlCommand command= new SqlCommand();
    command.CommandText = "UPDATE Table set column1 = @value where column2 = @number";
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@value", Value = "someValue", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar });
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@number", Value = 3, SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int });

    QueryDB(_connString, command));
}
```

In `Example1` I try disposing the `SqlCommand` but I don't know if it works like that. Another thing to considerate is that I'm running a timer every second that executes `Example1` or `Example2`, and I don't know if that has something to do with the problem, the Max pool size error happens sometimes, not everyday and it delays other queries. Is there something that I can do to improve this behavior? Thanks

Comment: try dispose it manually or try `SqlCommand.Cancel();` and `EndExecuteNonQuery();`

Comment: How long do the commands take to execute? If you're running them every second and they take more than one second, you might run into the issue because there are too many running in parallel.

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling?force_isolation=true

Comment: Closing the connection is the important bit. You won't be keeping pooled connections occupied just by having the instance an in `SqlCommand.Connection` property somewhere. Having said that, it won't hurt to set `SqlCommand.Connection` to `null` after  disposing the connection. This should not alleviate any problems you're now seeing, though.

Comment: @Christian Idk exactly how long it takes, sometimes 200ms or even 2 seconds (2 seconds if I'm getting the Connection Pool error), so maybe I should set the timeout to 1 ?

Comment: Rather than pass in the `SqlCommand` instance, consider passing in a delegate that gets called to populate the command, and construct the command instance internally.

Comment: @amirhoseinadlfar I'll try that, the ```EndExecuteNonQuery();``` is after I finish doing the ```ExecuteNonQuery();``` )

Comment: Could be your application has deadlocks that are piling up. In SSMS connect to the instance and use the Monitor view to take a look at active queries and open connections. You should be able to check the state. Are they all WAITING or perhaps something else? That should give you some more perspective as to what is actually happening.

Comment: But the code you have shown above in your question should not keep any open managed connections. There might be some unmanaged connections that are pooled by .net CLR but providing your app is executing OK these should be minimal.

Comment: `Example1` is fine. `Example2` is not (although it likely isn't causing the connection pooling issues).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to thank you all for your responses! After doing a lot of research and modifications, I implemented @Jack A's and @Jhon Busto's recomendations. But you where right John it didn't solve the connection pool problem, it turns out that the real problem was the timer, I didn't notice that it was constantly executing `Example1` and `Example2` but not every second, it was every 50ms or less, so I presume that it created a lot of connections in the pool. I was changing the `Timer.Interval` property of the timer but I didn't know this:

> If Enabled and AutoReset are both set to false, and the timer has previously been enabled, setting the Interval property causes the Elapsed event to be raised once, as if the Enabled property had been set to true. To set the interval without raising the event, you can temporarily set the Enabled property to true, set the Interval property to the desired time interval, and then immediately set the Enabled property back to false.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer.interval?view=netframework-4.7.2

So, if I needed to change the `Timer.Interval` I followed Microsoft's documentation, I tested everything again and it worked. Be careful using Timers! hehe :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know if this will solve your problem with respect to the connection pool issues, but, expanding on @Jack A's comment to your question, perhaps, a better way to structure your code would be to change your `QueryDB` method to take a delegate that updates the `SqlCommand` variable with the necessary information and, then, you can make sure both your `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` and taken care of correctly within that method.

```
private void QueryDB(string sConnString, Action<SqlCommand> commandDelegate)
{
    using (SqlConnection oCon = new SqlConnection(sConnString))
        using(SqlCommand oComm = new SqlCommand())
        {
            try
            {
                oCon.Open();
                oComm.Connection = oCon;
                oComm.CommandTimeout = 2;
                commandDelegate(oComm);
                oComm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (SqlException e)
            {
                //log exception
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //log exception
            }
        }
}
```

You could then use it in either of the following ways in your code:

```
public void Uses()
{
    QueryDB(_connString, (oComm) => oComm.CommandText = "SELECT TOP 1 FROM Table ORDER BY column1 DESC");

    QueryDB(_connString, longerDelegate);
}

private void longerDelegate(SqlCommand oComm)
{
    oComm.CommandText = "UPDATE Table set column1 = @value where column2 = @number";
    oComm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@value", Value = "someValue", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar });
    oComm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@number", Value = 3, SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int });
}
```

Again, I'm not sure this will solve your pooling problem, but it ensures everything is, at least, neatly wrapped in your `QueryDB` method.